# How to get latest record inserted by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables category and photos

**Category**

```
CATEGORYID CATEGORY
-------------------
1          Nature
2          Animals
3          Travelling
4          Foods
```

**photos**

```
    PHOTOID   FILENAME    CATEGORYID   URL                                       TIMEUPLOADED
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1001      file1.jpg   1            http://www.server.com/1001/file1.jpg      2015-12-25 19:21:22
    1002      file2.jpg   1            http://www.server.com/1002/file2.jpg      2015-12-24 19:21:22
    1003      file3.jpg   1            http://www.server.com/1003/file3.jpg      2015-12-22 19:21:22
    1004      file4.jpg   2            http://www.server.com/1004/file4.jpg      2015-12-21 19:21:22
    1005      file5.jpg   2            http://www.server.com/1005/file5.jpg      2015-12-20 19:21:22
    1006      file6.jpg   3            http://www.server.com/1006/file6.jpg      2015-12-19 19:21:22
    1007      file7.jpg   4            http://www.server.com/1007/file7.jpg      2015-12-18 19:21:22
    1008      file8.jpg   3            http://www.server.com/1008/file8.jpg      2015-12-17 19:21:22
    1009      file9.jpg   4            http://www.server.com/1009/file9.jpg      2015-12-16 19:21:22
```

I want latest photo uploaded in respective category and its image count like below output

```
PHOTOID   FILENAME    CATEGORYID  CATEGORY     URL                                       TIMEUPLOADED           IMGCOUNT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001      file1.jpg   1           Nature       http://www.server.com/1001/file1.jpg      2015-12-25 19:21:22    3
1004      file4.jpg   2           Animals      http://www.server.com/1004/file4.jpg      2015-12-21 19:21:22    2
1006      file6.jpg   3           Travelling   http://www.server.com/1006/file6.jpg      2015-12-19 19:21:22    2
1007      file7.jpg   4           Foods        http://www.server.com/1007/file7.jpg      2015-12-18 19:21:22    2
```

I tried using below query

```
SELECT t1.*,COUNT(*) AS IMGCOUNT FROM photos t1 GROUP BY CATEGORYID order by TIMEUPLOADED desc;
```

but it does not gives correct result

Below query gives latest photo uploaded in respective but it does not gives image count

```
 SELECT t1.*,COUNT(*) AS IMGCOUNT FROM photos t1
 LEFT JOIN category t2 on t1.CATEGORYID = t2.CATEGORYID
 JOIN (SELECT CATEGORYID, max(TIMEUPLOADED) maxdt FROM photos GROUP BY CATEGORYID) t3 ON t1.CATEGORYID = t3.CATEGORYID
 AND t1.TIMEUPLOADED = maxdt
 GROUP BY t1.CATEGORYID order by t1.TIMEUPLOADED desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.. I created a test table and ran.   You want the youngest photo posted for a given category.. and the total photo count for that category as well..

```
select 

tmp.categoryid,
tmp.mycount,
tmp.maxpid,
p4.filename,
p4.url,
p4.timeuploaded

from 
(select 

p.categoryid, 
count(p.photoid)as mycount,
(select max(photoid) 
  from test.photo p1 
  where p1.categoryid = p.categoryid and p1.timeuploaded = (
                        select max(p2.timeuploaded) from test.photo p2 
                           where p.categoryid = p2.categoryid)) as maxpid

from test.photo p group by p.categoryid)

as tmp

join test.photo p4 on

  p4.photoid = tmp.maxpid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the query as you want, because the CATEGORYID includes several filenames with different PHOTOID's. Unless you want to obtain the minimum or the maximum ones from those categories:

```
    select min(`PHOTOID`) as `PHOTOID`, min(`FILENAME`) as `FILENAME`,
     `CATEGORYID`, min(`URL`) as `URL`, min(`TIMEUPLOADED`) as `TIMEUPLOADED`,
     count(*) as 'IMGCOUNT' 
     from photos group by `CATEGORYID` order by `TIMEUPLOADED` desc;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5525a/6)